# Why I am getting swift Dynamic Cast failed?

Tags: swift, runtime-error, downcast

This line of code seems to be causing the problem

```
{
gymnastTables.gymnastsArray = defualts.objectForKey("Gymnasts") as Array
}
```

Why I am getting a downcast error?

Comment: I think you should post more code and report the complete error message. At a first glance, I'd say that the error is caused by the fact that the value corresponding to the "Gymnast" is not an Array. Have you tried saving it into a separate variable and checked it out?

Comment: Debugging: If possible reduce the problem to produce the problem with the least code. In this case `gymnastTables.gymnastsArray` is more complicated that `let x` for testing. Does `let x = defualts.objectForKey("Gymnasts") as Array` work? Is `defaults` good? Is there a `"Gymnasts"` element (you can check the default file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`objectForKey` has return type: `AnyObject?` therefore it might be `nil`

You can first unwrap it by `as AnyObject!` and after downcast to `Array`

```
gymnastTables.gymnastsArray = 
        defualts.objectForKey("Gymnasts") as AnyObject! as Array<AnyObject>
```

---

You didn't mention `Array` type so I added `AnyObject` that will be always true

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, you **have** to specify what type the `Array` contains, either like `Array<Gymnast>` or `[Gymnast]`.

Comment: May have been done, there is not enough code to tell.